How to solve duplicating update in Vuejs 2 component
I have a child component "DetailsDialog" in which I watch for a prop change and then request an API call. The problem is that the API call is executing twice instead of once, so, I believe is because the component is updating double. I am using VueJS 2.7, OptionsAPI and basically I just want that when I click a row in a datatable the app call an API to show data dynamically. I even called updated() hook and inside a console.log and indeed, is updating twice. So, I need to call the API just once in the component when its prop is updated. I'd appreciate the help, thanks in advance
// Component child DialogDetails.vue
props: {
    // other props {...},
    // desired prop
    selected_company: {
        type: Object,
        default() {
            return {}
        }
    },
},

watch: {
    selected_company(val) {
        if (val !== null) {
            this.apiCall()
        }
    },
},

// Event in other sibling component
rowClick: function (item, row) {
        this.$emit('openDetailsModal', {selected_user: null, selected_company: item, open_details: true})
    },

// Parent component     
<dialog-details :show-details-modal="open_details"
                :selected_company="selected_company" 
                @closeDialog="closeDetails" />

